# How to define input field (Selector) under condition to exist text in other class in the same div

Tags: testing, automated-tests, conditional-statements, selector, testcafe

I'm having trouble defining the field for typing  text into

```
this.requiredField = Selector('input').withAttribute('required');
```

in a condition where the validation label is

```
this.requiredLabel = Selector('.form-control-warning').withText('Required field cannot be left blank');
```

There are in class=”col-10” – see below

[image]

I am not interested in such a filed where there is no text Required field cannot be left blank in. form-control-warning
[image]

I need it because I must type text in each field with a label: 'Required field cannot be left blank" 
I created sth like this:

```
while (await epgBoard.requiredLabel.exists)
{

await t.typeText(epgBoard.emptyRequiredField, 'ff')
}
```

I have no idea how to define such selector

this.emptyRequiredField = 
find in .col-10 -> input  withAtrribute required where . form-control-warning has text Required field cannot be left blank

Could sb help me with this matter?

Answer (score 1):

The [withText](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/functional-style-selectors.html#withtext) method filters existing DOM Nodes, which contain the specified text. For instance:

```
<validation-message>Required field cannot be left blank</validation-message>
```

However, your markup does not seem to contain nodes with the specified text.

Instead, you can obtain the value of your input elements by using the [DOM Node State](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/dom-node-state.html). See if the `value` property meets your requirements. For instance:

```
const requiredFields = Selector('input').withAttribute('required');
const requiredFieldsCount = await requiredFields.count;

for (let i = 0; i < requiredFieldsCount; i++) {
    const field = requiredFields.nth(i);
    const fieldValue = await field.value;
    if (!fieldValue)
        await t.typeText(field, "dummy text");
}
```

See also:

[Obtain Element State](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/using-selectors.html#obtain-element-state)

[Enumerate Elements Identified by a Selector](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/examples-of-working-with-dom-elements.html#enumerate-elements-identified-by-a-selector)

Comment: Maybe your suggestion is right but I can't handle it:(

Comment: What do you mean by 'I can't handle it'?

Comment: I created

  {
    const requiredField = Selector('input').withAttribute('required')
    const requiredFieldValue = await requiredField.value;

    while (await requiredFieldValue)
      await t.typeText(requiredField, 'ff')

  }
and received the following error:
"Selector is not defined"

Comment: The requiredFieldValue is a variable holding the actual value (text, number, etc.) of your field. You can't "await" value and you can't use it in a while loop. You need to enumerate all required fields (Enumerate Elements Identified by a Selector), obtain their values, check them and do what you need. I've updated my sample in my answer.

Comment: See also: [Enumerate Elements Identified by a Selector](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/examples-of-working-with-dom-elements.html#enumerate-elements-identified-by-a-selector)

Comment: You are welcome. You can mark my answer as a solution, so other users refer to it first.